# how to make ng-repeat in table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i have a scenario every leave have a td of leave, use leave and credit

this is my problem [image]

i want to make it every leave they have a leave, use leave and credit

here my code

```
table.table1 border="1" ng-cloak=""
tr
  th.tg-031e
  th.tg-031e colspan="3" ng-repeat="leave in ctrl.leaves | orderBy: 'id'"
   | {{ leave.name }}
tr
  td.tg-031e
  td.tg-031e ng-repeat="leave in ctrl.leaves" leave
  td.tg-031e ng-repeat="leave in ctrl.leaves" Use leave
  td.tg-031e ng-repeat="leave in ctrl.leaves" credit left
```

please share your knowledge thanks

Comment: You'll basically need two loops. One for each table row and the other to fill the columns or you can have one loop for each row and set the values for the columns. The headers, however, have to be set manually.

Comment: thanks for the reply can give ma a jsfiddle so i can understand more :)

Comment: Would love to.. why not create one and share so that I can fork and send you a working version.

Comment: ok i will create a account